# Whenever running bitbake stops all application and locks the system

Tags: yocto, bitbake

When ever I am running "bitbake machine" command in yocto after certain time the the system is stopping the GNOME and closing all the applications eventually it re-directs to login page.I have attavhed my syslog here.
`gnome-session[12517]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:12657): Gdk-WARNING **: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

org.a11y.atspi.Registry[12461]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"

org.a11y.atspi.Registry[12461]:       after 2871 requests (2871 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

gnome-session[12517]: (unity-fallback-mount-helper:12655): Gdk-WARNING **: unity-fallback-mount-helper: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

gnome-session[12517]: (update-notifier:12906): Gdk-WARNING **: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

gnome-session[12517]: (nm-applet:12653): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

org.gnome.Terminal[12386]: (gnome-terminal-server:12811): Gdk-WARNING **: 
gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

gnome-session[12517]: (gnome-software:12654): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-software: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

gnome-session[12517]: (nautilus:12659): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
kernel: [172165.093743] show_signal_msg: 12 callbacks suppressed
kernel: [172165.093745] Chrome_~dThread[11021]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fa42a7178c6 sp 00007fa428814af0 error 6 in libxul.so[7fa4298de000+5826000]

gnome-session[12517]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory

gnome-session[12517]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

gnome-session[12517]: (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:24599): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

pulseaudio[24610]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
pulseaudio[24604]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I still do not know the cause of the logout issue, so I woudn't consider this a complete solution. In the meantime, I was able to complete a full build yesterday! I ran the full build while limiting the number of concurrent bitbake tasks allowed to 1. You can modify the number of concurrent tasks with the `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` variable in `build/conf/local.conf`:

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "1"
```

Once the full build completes, I stop experiencing this issue with subsequent or incremental builds for the same image. This isn't a permanent solution, but a quick way to get unblocked. I'll report back here if I learn anything more about this issue.

Comment: Yes, this method has solved the issue.This isn't the permanent solution,however it is solving the problem.

Comment: This work-around fixed it for me also.  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 lightdm/unity/compiz.  I strongly suspect one of them is hosing up. The syslog indicates the same set of GUI crashes before lightdm exits (killing all children including the yocto build.)  Long term solution could be to run the build inside a kvm or vbox.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but is there any real solution ?